# Batch download zips from ftp

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, ftp

Good evening.
Can You help me please with some batch file?
I have an ftp, where in root directory located few randomly named zip archives.
So i need to download that archives to local D:\temp
I know, how to do it via ftp.exe, but only for one file, witch name i know:

**file: save.bat**

```
ftp -s:1.txt
```

**file: 1.txt**

```
open myftp.com
123login
321pass
prompt
binary
hash
get file.zip D:\test\12.zip
bye
```

Maybe u can tell me how to download all * zip archives on ftp in loop?
Thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow isn't really a "please write this program for me" site. It's a "I'm writing a program, but I have a problem" site. So start writing your program and when you get stuck, ask your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `mget` command to download multiple files through `ftp`. This also supports wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
mget *.zip
```